# Deferring Angular until Firebase data received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Right now, I am having users input data on the a sign up page, which includes having the user input their "plan type". I store this user data on Firebase.

On the following page after the user has submitted the previous input page, I take the user to an output page that uses AngularJS to show all plans filtered by the user's "plan type" (in the code, it's the customFilter). So, as soon as the page loads, I want to be able to call the user's plan type from firebase and then make it the initial filter that customFilter uses.

How do I get the Angular filter to wait until I get the "plan type' from Firebase? Any examples would be much appreciated.

I've added the code below to make this easier to answer**

```
<body ng-app="tipOutput" ng-controller="Tips">
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
// Custom filter that I want to customize based on user data
   <span class="select">
      <select style="width:100%" ng-model="filterItem.plan" ng-options="item.name for item in filterOptions.plans"></select>
   </span>
// Table using ng-repeat and above filter
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tip in tips | filter:customFilter"> 
         <td style="vertical-align:top"><span><strong>{{tip.planName}}</strong></span><span ng-show="tip.planDetail">Plan Detail: {{tip.planDetail}}</span></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
```

**Angular app code here**

```
angular.module('tipOutput', ['firebase', 'filters'])
  .controller('Tips', ['$scope', 'angularFire', 
  function ($scope, angularFire) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://sitename.firebaseio.com/tips');
    angularFire(ref, $scope, "tips");
  }])
 .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

//Contains the filter options
  $scope.filterOptions = {
    plans: [
      {id : 2, name : 'All Plans', type: 'all' },
      {id : 3, name : 'Plan Type 1', type: 'plan-type-1' },
      {id : 4, name : 'Plan Type 2', type: 'plan-type-2' },
      {id : 5, name : 'Plan Type 3', type: 'plan-type-3' },
      {id : 6, name : 'Plan Type 4', type: 'plan-type-4' },
      {id : 7, name : 'Plan Type 5', type: 'plan-type-5' },
      {id : 8, name : 'Plan Type 6', type: 'plan-type-6' }  
    ]
  };
// Here's where the initial value of the filter is set. Currently, it's not dynamic, but I
// want it to be based off a variable that comes in asynchronously (i.e. likely after this
// code would otherwise run)
  $scope.filterItem = {
    plan: $scope.filterOptions.plans[0]
  }   
//Custom filter - filter based on the plan type selected
  $scope.customFilter = function (tip) {
    if (tip.servicesReceived === $scope.filterItem.plan.type) {
      return true;
    } else if ($scope.filterItem.plan.type === 'all') {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  };  
})
```

Comment: Probably be best if you post some code.  Not sure where you have AngularJS patched into the process.

Comment: Without code it's hard to say, but it sounds like you are making the asynchronous call outside of Angular? If this is the case you just need to make sure to do a $scope.$apply() so that Angular can recognize the updated value. In your case it may be $rootScope, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I added in the code - thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Is there a reason why you have two nested controllers? Maybe your angularFire call should be in a service called by `MainCtrl`.

Answer (score 3):

I tried to simulate your call to your firebase.

**DEMO**: http://plnkr.co/edit/VDmTCmR82IyaKnfaT1CP?p=preview

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

<div>
  <span class="select">
    <select ng-model="filterItem.plan" ng-options="item.name for item in filterOptions.plans"></select>
  </span>

  <table border="1">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="tip in (filtered = (tips | filter:customFilter))"> 
        <td>
          <span><strong>{{tip.planName}}</strong></span>
          <span>Plan Detail: {{tip.planDetail}}</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-show="filtered.length==0">
        <td>None</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
```

I keep the filtered list to be able to display a message if there is no items.

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, angularFire) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.tips = [];

  /*
  // since we dont have access to your firebase, i used a $timeout
  var ref = new Firebase('https://sitename.firebaseio.com/tips');

  // we wait for the callback of angularFire
  angularFire(ref, $scope, "tips").then(function(response) {
     var index = 1; // find the good index in filterOptions
     $scope.filterItem.plan = $scope.filterOptions.plans[index];
  });*/

  // simulate the response
  $timeout(function() {
      $scope.tips = [
        {planName: '213', planDetail:'534',servicesReceived:'plan-type-1'},
        {planName: '123', planDetail:'345',servicesReceived:'plan-type-2'},
        {planName: '321', planDetail:'643'} // this one has no serviceReceived
      ];
      // set it to the response receive from the server
      var response = 1;
      $scope.filterItem.plan = $scope.filterOptions.plans[response];
  }, 1000);

  $scope.filterOptions = {
    plans: [
      {id : 2, name : 'All Plans', type: 'all' },
      {id : 3, name : 'Plan Type 1', type: 'plan-type-1' },
      {id : 4, name : 'Plan Type 2', type: 'plan-type-2' },
      {id : 5, name : 'Plan Type 3', type: 'plan-type-3' },
      {id : 6, name : 'Plan Type 4', type: 'plan-type-4' },
      {id : 7, name : 'Plan Type 5', type: 'plan-type-5' },
      {id : 8, name : 'Plan Type 6', type: 'plan-type-6' }  
    ]
  };

  // default value
  $scope.filterItem = {
    plan: $scope.filterOptions.plans[0] // Do something with response
  }

  $scope.customFilter = function (tip) {
    return (tip.servicesReceived || 'all') === $scope.filterItem.plan.type;
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! So, if I'm understanding this correctly, this code does not delay loading until the server responds, but instead loads a default value and then updates the filter as soon as the server response is in.

Comment: Also, if, for example, the server came back with "plan-type-1" - how would I map this to $scope.filterOptions.plans[1], since that is the way the filter works?

Comment: Yes that's right, You would have to loop through the plans array and find the one corresponding and set it to your filterOptions.plan!

Comment: This is a good answer. But people should be warned introducing more logic into the view that probably should be in the controller is a really bad idea. Ideally, the filtering would be done in the controller so that unit tests could be written reliably. Angular's expression engine is very powerful, which is cool, but it allows for goofy things, like variable assignment (e.g. `tip in (filtered = (tips | filter:customFilter))`) ... which is really an anti-pattern when it comes to the tenets of MVC-like frameworks and testability.

Comment: ... in fairness, if you dig through some of my answers, I've recommended this pattern in the past. But working in an environment that requires thorough testing, I've since learned better.

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the fireBase Data on the route. This will prohibit the controller from loading before the data is present. Then just inject the data into the controller and continue forward with your normal process.

I'm not going to write it using your variables, but an exmaple of such a config file would look like:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('someModule.dashboard')
 .config(function ($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('dashboard', {
    url: '/dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/app/dashboard/html/dashboard.html',
    controller: 'dashBoardCtrl',
    resolve: {
      currentAuth: function(fireBaseAuth){
        return fireBaseAuth.auth().$requireAuth();
      },
      currentUser: function($fireBaseUser, Session){
       return $fireBaseUser.user(Session.id).$asObject();
      },
      userList: function($fireBaseUser){
        return $fireBaseUser.userList().$asArray();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Then Your controller would look something like this:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('someModule.dashboard')
  .controller('dashBoardCtrl', function($scope, currentUser, userList){
   $scope.userList = userList;
});
```